# How to Set Up environment for Jigsaw - W3C's Server in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: webserver

I am trying to install the Jigsaw web server by w3c in `ubuntu 18.04`. And I am not able to understand this step Kindly check the attached image & also need a guide on how to proceed with this step in the terminal. If possible with images.

**Jigsaw environment path**
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

W3C Jigsaw is an ancient Java webserver that was implemented in the 1990s as a demo / proof of concept platform by W3C people. The final release was Jigsaw 2.2.6 which was released in 2007. About 15 years ago. It requires Java 1.2 or later and was only tested up to Java 6.

You are apparently trying to run it using the OpenJDK Java that is available with Ubuntu Xenial. That will be Java 8.

Now you *might* be able to get it to work.  There is a `README` file, and the instructions in the file look plausible.  Indeed, they are straightforward for someone who understands Java to follow.

One thing to note is that the Jetty codebase includes a UNIX specific native code library.  What would almost certainly need to be rebuilt from the C source code included in the ZIP file.  That may present some problems; e.g. on Windows.

---

However, the real question is: *What are you trying to achieve?*

This Jigsaw server is not something you would actually want to use.  There are other, many *much* more modern web server / web container implementations out there.  Including "small footprint" servers like Jetty ... if that is your motivation.

Unless you are doing this to research / understand Jigsaw itself (e.g. as a code archeology or retro-computing exercise), I think you are going to find that building and running Jetty is a waste of time.

You clarified:

> I am collecting details of first world wide web browser and so on. I saw W3C Jigsaw, and instead of just saying the name I decided to create a video how it works and so this attempt.

<sup>(Note: W3C Jigsaw is not the first webserver.  The first webserver software was [CERN httpd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CERN_httpd) which predates Jigsaw by ~8 years.)</sup>

OK so that is a speculative and "once off" use-case.  I'm not convinced that it is worth my effort to write you a bunch of new instructions for building W3C Jigsaw.  And I can't see that these instructions would be useful to anyone else.  So you would be better off either:

- Doing some more reading about Java and native code so that the instructions make sense to you.
- Asking specific questions about specific problems you have encountered.
- Going to a rent-a-coder site and *pay* someone to do the setup for you and/or write some clearer build / installation instructions for you.

(Though ... on the last point ... you are liable to just get a second set of instructions that you don't understand either.  Coders don't *like* writing documentation, and are typically not good at writing clear build / installation instructions.)

---

In case you were wondering, the W3C Jigsaw webserver is nothing to do with the Jigsaw project that produced the modularized Java SE codebase.  (Your question tags are incorrect.)

Comment: Hi, ~yes . through internet , i am collecting details of first world wide web browser and so on. In this travel , i saw W3C Jigsaw , instead of just saying the name , i decided to create a video how it works and so this attempt.

Comment: ok. Thank you for the suggestions . A small clarification from my side . Yes, CERN httpd is the first web server . As said earlier , in this " internet travel" (i am organizing my level best) , i felt this particular old software will be easier for me to show demos compared to first web server & so tried . Anyway it's ok. Once again thankyou for your dedicational writing. :)